# Socket Error while sending data as chunks

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to send and receive data by chunking it, When I send data once, it works perfectly, but when I do it two times, (as multiple send and receive statements) then nothing shows up, looks like it got stuck in an infinite loop.

**server.py**

```
import socket

ADDR = ('localhost', 9999)
BUFFER = 1024

def chunk_data(data):
    for i in range(0, len(data), BUFFER):
        yield data[i: i+BUFFER]

def sendData(conn, data):
    data_chunked = list(chunk_data(data))
    if len(data_chunked[-1]) != BUFFER:
        data_chunked[-1] += (BUFFER - len(data_chunked[-1])) * b' '

    for chunk in data_chunked:
        conn.send(chunk)

def recvData(conn):
    data = b''
    chunk = conn.recv(BUFFER)
    data += chunk
    while chunk:
        chunk = conn.recv(BUFFER)
        data += chunk

    return data

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(ADDR)
s.listen()

conn, addr = s.accept()
sendData(conn, b'Connection Established Successful')
print(recvData(conn).strip())
sendData(conn, b'Helo')
print(recvData(conn).strip())

conn.close()
s.close()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket

ADDR = ('localhost', 9999)
BUFFER = 1024

def chunk_data(data):
    for i in range(0, len(data), BUFFER):
        yield data[i: i+BUFFER]

def sendData(conn, data):
    data_chunked = list(chunk_data(data))
    if len(data_chunked[-1]) != BUFFER:
        data_chunked[-1] += (BUFFER - len(data_chunked[-1])) * b' '

    for chunk in data_chunked:
        conn.send(chunk)

def recvData(conn):
    data = b''
    chunk = conn.recv(BUFFER)
    data += chunk
    while chunk:
        chunk = conn.recv(BUFFER)
        data += chunk

    return data

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(ADDR)

print(recvData(s).strip())
sendData(s, b'heheh')
print(recvData(s).strip())
sendData(s, b'woieruer')


s.close()
```

What is causing this problem? How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is stuck waiting for more data.

In the code below, it assumes there will be more after the first chunk - but that's not always the case so you need to handle that.

```py
def recvData(conn):
    data = b''
    chunk = conn.recv(BUFFER)
    data += chunk
    while chunk:
        chunk = conn.recv(BUFFER)
        print('is chunk')
        data += chunk

    return data
```

You can try to limit the while to check the size of the returned data:

```py
    while chunk and len(chunk) == BUFFER:
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer, but when i add that while condition, its not making any change, it is still stuck the statement "is chunk" is also not printed